# How to connect and fetch page from web using HTTP?

Tags: centos, julia

Objective: To fetch webpage using package HTTP in julia:
Environment: CentOS7.4
Content of fetch.jl:

```
#! /opt/julia/julia-1.1.0/bin/julia

using HTTP,  Cascadia, Gumbo; 

function fetch()
    url ="https://www.google.com";
    #url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/Stack_Overflow";
    #url ="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia";
    parsedPage = parsehtml(String(HTTP.get(url)));
    println(string(parsedPage));
end
fetch();
```

invoking `julia>/home/julia/fetch.jl` shows as follows:

```
...
ERROR: LoadError: IOError(Base.Error(connect: host is unreachable(EHOSTUNREACH)", -113), during request(https://www.google.com))
...
```

Observation:
a) These sites are opening in browser(Mozilla Firefox).
b) wget fetches the pages
c) Also, tried with i) switching off both firewall (using `systemctl stop firewalld`) and selinux (using `setenforce 0`). 
ii) other urls.  But, no success!

Please help me in connecting and fetching webpages using HTTP!

Comment: code is okay. it works for me

Comment: can you ping www.google.com? `ping www.google.com`..DNS probably isn't configured..

Comment: Yes! Even wget https://www.google.com fetches the page!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be valid.

Try connecting using plain sockets and see what happens:

```
julia> using Sockets

julia> t = connect("google.com", 80)
TCPSocket(Base.Libc.WindowsRawSocket(0x000000000000037c) open, 0 bytes waiting)

julia> println(t, "GET /")

julia> readline(t)
"HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
```